# Eclipse - Searching for strings in JRE System Libraries or Referenced Libraries does not work

Tags: eclipse

I can easily search files, folders or the whole workspace with the search function, but whenever I select either 'JRE System Library' or 'Referenced Libraries' Eclipse always returns "'*' - 0 matches in empty scope". I even checked 'Consider derived resources' but to no avail.

I am aware that these files are read-only, but why is it that I cannot search through them?

Comment: Which of the many Searches supported by Eclipse are you asking about?

Comment: @greg449, I want to search for a string of text, so I am using the 'Search' tab at the top of the screen (File, Menu etc...) and I'm using 'File Search'

Comment: My File Search does not have 'JRE System Library' or 'Referenced Libraries' as options.